# KMP: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void org.jetbrains.skia.CanvasKt._nTranslate(long, float, float)'

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

My Desktop Compose application doesn't run anymore (fails with an error) in my IDE or via gradle. It has been months since last time I touched the project and the application run properly. I've no idea how the project got to this state.

`build.gradle.kts` plugin versions:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.8.20"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.4.1"
    id("io.realm.kotlin") version "1.7.1"
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void org.jetbrains.skia.CanvasKt._nTranslate(long, float, float)'
    at org.jetbrains.skia.CanvasKt._nTranslate(Native Method)
    at org.jetbrains.skia.CanvasKt.access$_nTranslate(Canvas.kt:1)
    at org.jetbrains.skia.Canvas.translate(Canvas.kt:1085)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SkiaBackedCanvas.translate(SkiaBackedCanvas.skiko.kt:85)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.CanvasDrawScopeKt$asDrawTransform$1.inset(CanvasDrawScope.kt:763)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter.draw-x_KDEd0(Painter.kt:218)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter.draw-x_KDEd0$default(Painter.kt:185)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.PainterImage.asBitmap(DesktopImageConverters.desktop.kt:164)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.PainterImage.getResolutionVariant(DesktopImageConverters.desktop.kt:151)
```

Comment: this looks like internal issue - create an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and report it to [project github](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform)

Comment: @PhilDukhov I was about to prepare one but after updating to v1.5.0-dev1114 it got fixed fortunately

Comment: I only get this when upgrading from 1.3.1 to 1.5.0-beta01. 1.4.3 is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with

```
id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.6.0-dev1296"
```

it got fixed fortunately

Comment: Could you please explain why this works?

Comment: I suppose that jetbrains fixed that issue with later versions